# Why Is My If Statement Crashing WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, wordpress-theming

I'm an experienced web developer, so I'm embarrassed to ask this, but why is my if statement cashing WordPress?

```
<!-- THE BLOCK FOR THE HEADER IN THE CMS !-->
<span class="PostHeader"><p>
<?php

    if(empty(get_the_block("Header"))){
        echo "Employment"; //Empty only on the employment screen
    } else {
        the_block("Header");
    }

?>
</p>
<!-- END OF THE BLOCK -->
```

This is in a template for Wordpress, and if I comment out the control structure, it loads fine, but as soon as I try to let it run in the template, the page just stops loading.

Why is it doing this?

--EDIT--

Sorry forgot to mention that the "Multiple Content Blocks" Plugin is enabled.

Comment: did you check the server's error logs for any details?

Comment: I am not familiar with wordpress, I am assuming that the functions are defined for "get_the_block", and "the_block"? Try enabling php debugging to see any visible errors, or check the server logs for errors.

Comment: Nothing is showing up in the error logs, other than that it's missing the favicon that's specified.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, the page still crashes even if I try "if(empty(''))"

Comment: Should `the_block()` be `get_the_block()` in the `else`?

Comment: `the_block` echos the contents whereas `get_the_block` returns the contents, so no, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

empty() is a structure not a function, it only accepts variables, you should use this instead:

```
<!-- THE BLOCK FOR THE HEADER IN THE CMS !-->
<span class="PostHeader"><p>
<?php

    $block = get_the_block("Header");

    if(empty($block)){
        echo "Employment"; //Empty only on the employment screen
    } else {
        the_block("Header");
    }

?>
</p>
<!-- END OF THE BLOCK -->
```

For further informations see [PHP Empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: Yazmat, you are a lifesaver. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `get_the_block()` according to the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org).

Unless you've defined it or have a plugin that has defined it, you're getting a fatal error. Your server's error logs will likely confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

You must download this plugin : http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/multiple-content-blocks.zip and install it.

The function you try to use aren't in the WordPress Codex and are also not found. That's why you get a blank page aka the white screen of death (also because php reporting_error is set to false). You can try to put this line

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

in front of your if else statement.

Material :

> http://plugins.trendwerk.nl/documentation/multiple-content-blocks/